# distinct rows when looking at selected columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with 6 column that lists order lines.
the columns are Order, Orderline, ProductName, Description, UpdateDate, Location.

What I want to do is looking at values for first 4 columns (order, Line, ProductName, description).

If the rows are not identical in these four columns I want to return
   Order, Line, Name, and Description and update dates.

If they are identical I want to
   return just one of rows back (first or last).

```
Order   LineNumber  ProductName  description  UpdateDate  Location
Order1  1           a1           b1           d1          n
Order1  1           a1           b1           d2          m
Order1  1           a3           b3           d5          L
Order2  1           a1           b1           d3          o
Order2  2           a2           b2           d4          m
```

I want the result to be:

```
Order   LineNumber  ProductName  description  UpdateDate  Location
Order1  1           a1           b1           d1          n
Order1  1           a3           b3           d5          L
Order2  1           a1           b1           d3          o
Order2  2           a2           b2           d4          m
```

For Order1:

line 1 repeated 3 times.
 2 times out of three ProductName a1, and description b1 are identical so one of these two will be returned.
 1 time out of three productName a3 and description b3 is unique so this line will be returned as well.

For Order2:

all lines are identical unigue in Name and description so both lines will be returned.

Any help appriciated

Comment: I don't understand. You said looking at ProductName and Description. If they are identical then return one row. Well the first 3 rows all have the same ProductName and Description so I don't understand the output you put.

Comment: Thx for time, i edited my question and table to be more clear. please let me know if you got what I mean. It is hard to explain. I hope the table and result table make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Order], LineNumber, ProductName, [DESCRIPTION] ORDER BY UpdateDate) AS RowNum
  FROM YourTable) DerivedTable
WHERE RowNum = 1
```